# Employer asking for notice period

Tags: software-industry, india, relieving-letter

I am working for a small IT company in Chennai, India. I worked for 1.5 yrs and after that i gave 3 months notice period because its a clause in appointment letter and completed it.

During my notice period at end of it my employer told me to work for 5 more months because he could not get any other. So I kept working for 5 more months and on last day i asked him for my relieving letter.

Now my employer is asking for 3 months of notice period again.I am really shocked.Now i understood he is playing some tactics to make me stay here. I have to leave within 10 days for higher education.

Comment: What is the use of a relieving letter? Normally you would just not show up for work the day after your notice period is over.

Comment: You will have to ask a local lawyer.

Comment: Do you have anything at all from your employer indicating when your employment ends?

Comment: At the end of my notice period he told me to work for 5 more months. This is a in-person meeting.

Comment: @Egor Relieving letter is mandatory to prove work experience.

Comment: Do you have any of these promises from your employer in writing or via email?

Comment: This really is a legal question.  IANAL but conversations are hard to prove without witnesses.  Try to get this commitment from them in writing somehow or I fear your going to continue to struggle.

Comment: Is this a repost of a deleted question? Why was the first question deleted?

Comment: @DavidK perhaps they did not like the comments / answers...

Answer (score 8):

As the old saying goes, fool me once shame on you, fool me twice...

I do know India has horrible employment laws and you need to be "relieved" by your current employer before going elsewhere. As such, I would go ask a lawyer.

Comment: I do know India has <strike>horrible</strike> no employment laws.

Comment: If there were no employment laws, then employers couldn't blackmail their employees by withholding these damned relieving letters.